# How to provide the information (in html) for the label selected from the option in flask webpage?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col c12 aligncenter">
            <h2>List</h2>

            
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ analyze }}" id="textform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h3>List of proteins</h3>
                        </label>
                        <select id="List of proteins" class="" name="LoP">                              
                                <option HREF="#table1">Muc</option>
                                <option HREF="#table2">Sph</option>
                                <option HREF="#table3">Gle</option>
                                <option HREF="#table4">gens</option>
                                <option HREF="#table5">ses</option>
                                
                            </select>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col c12"> 
                            <br/><input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" class="button" value="Clear"/>
                        </div>
```

Dear friends,
This the the HTMl file that i have and i want to show up the information stored in table1.html file once i select the MUC option and submit it in the flask webpage using the post and get option?
Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add value attr for your options.with this you will get the value in `request.form` in your flask code.Then you can decide what response you want to return.

Comment: Thnaks for your help. I tried to add the Value attr to the html file and used the below code but it showsBad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: @app.route('/classifications/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def classifications():
 if request.method == 'POST':
  query_code = request.form('Muc')
  return render_template('test.html')
 else:
  return render_template('classifications.html')

Comment: Request form is a dictionary. If you print it you got it. your value is in `request.form['LoP']`

Comment: @app.route('/classifications/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def classifications():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    query_code = request.form['proteins']
    return render_template('test.html')
 else:
    return render_template('classifications.html')                                        How do I provide html link for the five data in the post and get flask. please do help me.

Comment: Use it `request.form` like this: `if request.form['LoP'] == 'Muc'` and ...